# Selecting Rows by percentage of chance

Tags: mysql

This is the table structure and it only contains these two rows:

```
--------------------------
|id   | item  | priority |
--------------------------
|1    | item1 | 20       |
--------------------------
|2    | item2 | 30       |
--------------------------
```

I have to write a query on the table to get any of these 2 rows or nothing by percentage of chance.

20% chance to get item1

30% chance to get item2

50% chance to get nothing

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Here's a technically flawed solution, but it should at least serve as a proof of concept... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iqDCVVfqWB8j334iiifyXB/0

Comment: Thanks strawberry.. it seems working...

Answer (score 1):

Below works on `MySQL`, `MariaDB` and `MS SQL Server`.

```
SELECT id, item, priority
FROM (
  SELECT rand() * 100 as rnd
) r
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(priority), 0) FROM my_table WHERE id < t.id) as range_start
  FROM my_table t
) mt
ON r.rnd between mt.range_start and (mt.priority + mt.range_start);
```

**PostgreSQL**
replace `rand()` with `random()`.

**SQLite**
replace `rand() * 100` with `ABS(RANDOM() % 100)`.

**Oracle**
replace `SELECT rand() * 100 as rnd` with `SELECT dbms_random.value() * 100 as rnd FROM DUAL`.

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL-8.0+/MariaDB-10.2+ window functions:

```
SELECT item
FROM
  (SELECT item,
          SUM(priority) OVER (
                              ORDER BY id) AS cum_prob
   FROM my_table) AS b
WHERE cum_prob >= RAND()*100
ORDER BY cum_prob
LIMIT 1
```

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1a8e96f5247d243d4e0b55bec07a3a57)